# Qt QML and QDBus interoperability

Tags: qt, properties, qml, dbus, networkmanager

There is a property system in Qt. Properties can be exposed *from* D-Bus using subclassing of `QDBusAbstractInterface` from the one hand and *to* Qt QML from the other hand. For properties and signals of D-Bus services interfaces it can be done by meta-object compiler automatically. For signals, slots and properties of `QObject` for QML it also can be done automatically by MOC.

But the problem arises: QML needs property and method (either signal or slot) names to be started from lowercase letter, while, say, Network Manager DBus API exports objects with all members identifiers starting with uppercase letters (sometimes with lowercase letters, say `org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.state()` method). But I want to use such an `QDBusAbstractInterface`-derived objects directly into QML code.

Is there a way to automatically translate methods' and properties' names into one form for `QtQml` and into another form for `QDBus`?

[Example](https://pastebin.com/DJ8AkzVz) of how to emit a signals for all the properties of NetworkManager objects separately.

Added: KDE NetworkManager Qt is not too useful in the light of the question, because there is no properties to be exported with QObject-s in QML.

Comment: See what qdbusxml2cpp creates: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdbusxml2cpp.html and if that may help.

Comment: @AlexanderVX I rejected `qdbusxml2cpp` tool because CMake scripts can't generate proper sources for me (maybe it is just outdated support from Qt community, I use 3.9 version of cmake and `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/usr/local/Qt-5.9.1/`). Also see an example from the question: `qdbusxml2cpp` can't create signals for `NOTIFY` section of properties in case of NetworkManager. It can be done only by hands in the case.

Comment: You can run qdbusxml2cpp just once and use the product as normal source code. I see the other reasons though. In case of NetworkManager you can try KDE QtNetworkManager. I did not initially pay attention what DBUS API is that. https://api.kde.org/frameworks-api/frameworks-apidocs/frameworks/networkmanager-qt/html/index.html

Comment: @AlexanderVX My code based on `networkmanager-qt`. But instructions from the beggining of the [file](https://github.com/KDE/networkmanager-qt/blob/master/src/dbus/CMakeLists.txt) does not works on my system.

Comment: I can assume your system is Linux and it is includable in the project by QT += NetworkManagerQt and I also set QMAKEPATH=$(QTDIR):/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5 or appended QMAKEPATH to where that library installed. Don't build it on your system though just do sudo apt-get install libkf5networkmanagerqt-dev Use C++ framework then and you can expose QObject based-stuff to QML or even create your own QML C++ items which I do.

Comment: @AlexanderVX I use CMake. Thank you anyways.

Comment: Enormous signal dispatcher [NetworkManager::DevicePrivate::propertyChanged](https://github.com/KDE/networkmanager-qt/blob/master/src/device.cpp#L216) - is it really unavoidable to glue two API?

Comment: In my project I don't have QML directly talking to NetworkManager and all that stuff in C++ and I never care about all signals and use very few.

Comment: as part of my `qdbusxml2cpp` script i run the resulting .h and .cpp files through some `sed` commands which change the capitilization of the methods and properties in the `QDBusAbstractInterface` subclass. The class then acts as an interface between the two worlds, just as it should. It took a while to prepare the script, but now it takes only a moment to run again when the dbus apis change, and the capitilization is compliant on both sides. I suppose now I should post the script, give me some time to sanitise it.

Comment: @MarkCh I want to check if script works. I sure letter case is crucial not only for QML, but for D-Bus too.

Comment: okay I will post an example of the output so you can see, I will have to post the script later

Comment: I thought I had all this working, but I can see that what I have provided isn't working. The code I have in my project is not how I remembered. I will delete the answer, and provide another if I get it sorted.